# Is the object passed in prepare a singelton ?What's the different?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, design-patterns, singleton

I notice that a object pass between two view controllers has the same address in those two controllers. And if I change the value in controller B, the value of object in controller A is changed automatically.
That inspire me to consider the object is a singelton..For singelton design pattern, the advantage is using a global valuable to saving the system resource and keep the consistency of the object.What I am thinking is right? Is there any difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. An object passed between two view controller can be the same object if
   you use **strong** property.It also can be two different objects if
   you use **copy** property.
2. If you use a singleton.It will be the same instance of one
   class.When using singleton,you should be carefully manage the life
   circle of it.

**It is about design.**

When using object pass between viewControllers,only the two viewControllers can access the object.

But,when using singleton,every place of your application can access the instance.

Answer (score 0):

The Singleton design pattern ensures that only one instance exists for a given class and that there’s a global access point to that instance. It usually uses lazy loading to create the single instance when it’s needed the first time.

> Apple uses this approach a lot. For example: [NSUserDefaults
>   standardUserDefaults], [UIApplication sharedApplication], [UIScreen
>   mainScreen], [NSFileManager defaultManager] all return a Singleton
>   object.

For more about Singleton design pattern go through the [Link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns)

Answer (score 0):

In [Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW7) or swift all what you call as "Object" is a pointer to object. It is not a object in C++ terms, it is a pointer in the C++ terms.

Because variable it is pointer, then you use a variable to call functions, the pointer is copied but not a pointed object.

But in Objective-C exist a C objects (structures (CGSize for example) and simple variables (int, float ...)), these variables will be copied if you will use them to call functions.

About properties: property it is methods (set and get, if property not readonly).

If property have parameter strong (retain):

```
@property (strong) NSObject* a
```

then it property can be implemented like a function:

```
- (void)setA:(NSObject*)a
{
    _a  = a;//or [_a release]; _a = [a retain]; if no ARC
}
```

If property have parameter copy:

```
@property (copy) NSObject* a
```

then it property can be implemented like a function:

```
- (void)setA:(NSObject*)a
{
    _a  = [a copy];//or [_a release]; _a = [a copy]; if no ARC
}
```

Property it is a method!

You can create many instances of any object classes:

```
NSObject* a = [[NSObject alloc] init];
NSObject* b = [[NSObject alloc] init];
```

a and b its pointers to different objects in a [memory](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1).

But if you not allocate b object:

```
NSObject* a = [[NSObject alloc] init];
NSObject* b = a;
```

a and b its pointers to one object in the memory.

About singleton: [the singleton pattern is a design pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).